# TinyMCE - Use single quotes instead of double quotes in the Link tool

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE in Wordpress 4.1. When I add a link via the Link tool, I need to use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>Google</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

After adding the Link using the add/edit Link button, I can switch over to text view and fix the urls, but after I save if I edit the page again in Visual view, it adds the double quotes back.
Is there a configuration option for this, or another way I can force the Link tool to build urls with single quotes?

Added:

A plugin I use to build bootstrap tables has a shortcode that looks like this:

```
[tboot_table strip="yes" border="yes" condense="yes" hover="yes" cols="Age,Time,Register" data="Ages 3-4,9:00AM - 9:55AM,<a href='myurl.com' target='_blank'>Register</a>"]
```

If I have double quotes in the URL, it breaks the table.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Updated my question with the "why".

Comment: From what I can see, that's a premium plugin. The documentation on it is not publicly available. I'd recommend you contact the developer about this issue.

Comment: That's why I was looking for a fix in TinyMCE.